# What does it mean by leading contribution in error calculation?

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, physics, mathematical-physics

I have an error as 0.012480556357032935 
The question asks to find propotionality to another variable and the leading contribution in error? Would that mean 0.012?

Comment: Without the full question there is no answer.

Comment: No. What does the error depend on? The leading term means that it's the biggest contribution to it.